Hosting Collab Notebook Python Script
I developed a script in Google Colab that implements my trained model, which requires an NVIDIA GPU to load because I used the Unsloth library for fast loading. I used ngrok to handle model requests in my web app, which is hosted on a live server. Now, I want to host my notebook on the live server, but the problem is that I can't run the Python script on the server since it lacks an NVIDIA GPU. I'm wondering if there's a way to make my Colab notebook work on the live server.
I researched and found some articles that google collab RDP can solve the problem but it have 72 hours limitation and I need my notebook to be permanently on live
